# Dispose ApplicationDbContext in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a web application and host it in Azure but the problem is that the SQL pool gets full fast regardless of tier.
I was thinking that maybe I need to dispose ApplicationDbContext, is this required? would this help?

The following is a part of my class with the method Index utilizing most of SQL time:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

public MessagesController(ApplicationDbContext context, IEmailSender emailSender)
{
    _context = context;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}

// GET: Message
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).Select(u =>
    new { u.Name, u.Subdomain, u.PhotoURL }).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewData["Name"] = user.Name;
    ViewData["Subdomain"] = user.Subdomain;
    ViewData["PhotoURL"] = (user.PhotoURL == null) ? "../../img/avatar.png" : user.PhotoURL;
    List<Message> messages = await _context.Messages.Where(m => m.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name))
    .Select(m => new Message { ID = m.ID, DateTime = m.DateTime, Text = m.Text }).ToListAsync();
    return View(messages);
}
```

Should I call _context.dispose() although I'm using the same context in other ActionResult methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to call _context.dispose() - the IoC container will release resources based on the lifetime setting which was used while registering them.

What is more, you wrote that "*I'm using the same context in other ActionResult methods?*". That's not true - well at least it shouldn't be true. The context should be created per request. So that while calling each of the controller actions your are generating new request and container is creating new context to be injected (each time when new request is done the controller is created once again).

Here is how you should register your context:

```
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(CONNECTION_STRING));
```

By this you are using default lifetime for DbContext - scoped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done what you wrote above, should I enclose it in using statement? because I still don't understand why my pool gets full very fast. Can you kindly tell me if I have any problem with the code above?